# FFMpeg to decode Closed Captions

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, hls

I have 150+ stream URLs, some with 608 captions, some with 708 captions, some with no captions, and others with a combination of two and multiple renditions of each.

The goal: input URLs to FFMpeg and have it spit out the type of captions present per stream.

I do not seem to get any useable output when I use a network stream URL for movie input in the following:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i movie=input.ts[out+subcc]  -map 0:1  output.srt
```

output:

```
semccart$ ffmpeg -f lavfi -i movie=https://hostname.com/master.m3u8?token [out+subcc]  -map 0:1  output.srt
[5] 16438
[6] 16439
-bash: -map: command not found
[6]   Done                    cdn=sa
bos-mpfnp:~ semccart$ ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lzma --enable-gnutls --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --disable-libxcb --disable-libxcb-shm --disable-libxcb-xfixes --disable-indev=jack --disable-outdev=xv --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-sdl2 --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/cc --enable-vda --enable-videotoolbox --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
```

This is where it just hangs. I have tried for TS segments directly as well.

Furthermore, how would i do this at scale, with multiple source URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169910/can-ffmpeg-extract-closed-caption-data) answer to this question?

Some people have had luck with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -an -vn -c:s copy -f rawvideo -map 0:s sub.txt
```

They are able to use non-ts file ending videos.